# My C code is not responding after scanf statement

Tags: c, scanf

I have wrote a set of code that scan in values and use them to test out central limit theorem. However when I run my program after I input all the values using scanf my program is not proceeding to the next lines of code : the problem looks like this:

```
printf("*** DEMONSTRATION OF CENTRAL LIMIT THEOREM ***");
printf("Enter parameters for the distribution [a b]    ==> ");
scanf("%f %f",&a,&b);
printf("Enter distribution to display [1=data, 2=mean] ==> ");
scanf("%d",&option);
printf("Enter number in each group                     ==> ");
scanf("%d",&group);
printf("Enter number of samples of groups              ==> ");
scanf("%f",&times);
printf("are we here yet");
```

after these printf and scanf the program starts to do the calculations. But When I run  the program after I compile(successfully). It seems my code is stuck after the scanf("%f",&times);

the line "are we here yet" never gets printed, meaning the program did not get past the scanf. I have not done much C programming this seemed really strange to me can someone figure out why the program is not excuting past the line scanf("%f",&times); I really appericate it

Comment: What happens after the `printf()` call? Are you sure this isn't just because you're not including a `'\n'` at the end of it, or making a call to `fflush(stdout)`?

Comment: after the printf() I have a if statement that checks for the input value of option, if the option is 1 it goes through a series of algorithms try to display the central limit theorem through pure data, if option==2 it display central limit theorem through mean of data. But the problem is after scanf nothing displays

Comment: when I run the program it goes something like this 
Enter parameters for the distribution [a b]    ==> 0.2 0.7

Enter distribution to display [1=data, 2=mean] ==> 2

Enter number in each group                     ==> 10

Enter number of samples of groups              ==> 100

Comment: Try changing to `printf("are we here yet\n");`. If that doesn't work, post your whole code, or the smallest version of it you can make that will exhibit this behavior.

Comment: yes you are right after I add \n it prints out the next line are we here yet so is not the problem with scanf but something else in my code that is causing the problem

Comment: thank you now I can narrow down my error. Lots of thanks

Comment: OP, as a general recommendation, debuggers are much more reliable and informative than `printf`. I recommend learning to use whichever debugger your IDE comes with. If you are not using an IDE, then there are still standalone debuggers (like gdb), and you should really consider using a good IDE if you can.

Comment: any good recommendations? I normally use C++ and java .net but not much experience with any C debugger.

Comment: Is `times` an `int`? You you have `scanf("%f", &times);` which expects a pointer to a `float`.

Comment: no that is not the problem it turned out to be fine I think is something to do with my algorithms I used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input/output at the terminal is line-buffered in C, and output is not going to display until you output a newline character, or you call `fflush(stdout)`, or your program terminates normally and all the buffers are flushed anyway. Change:

```
printf("are we here yet");
```

to:

```
printf("are we here yet\n");
```

or:

```
printf("are we here yet");
fflush(stdout);
```

and you should see your output.

Comment: thank you I realised that scanf is not causing the problem after using that. because the line after that scanf did get printed  It is something else in my code --algorithm part grrrr I am going to try fix it now